# Event that occurs when users Log in to Xbox Live Services on UWP through win+g shortcut

Tags: uwp

What is the event that occurs when user logs in to application through win+g shortcut -> accounts? I'd like to do perform an action when this happens.

Comment: In Windows 10, Win + G will bring up the game menu. Can you describe your intent, do you want to capture Win + G shortcuts?

Comment: When I press Win + G shortcut it shows game menu, yes. But if you move to "Options" then to "Accounts Bar" you can log off and log in here to chosen account. Now I'd like to know if there are some Events in Microsoft libraries that capture On Log in/ On Log off button click.

Comment: I am afraid this cannot be done. The game menu is independent of your application, you cannot capture pointer actions in another application.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer. Im sorry for beeing unclear.

Comment: Hi, If you still have questions about this issue, please feel free to ask